# Collection of pairwise non-isomorphic infinite self-complementary graphs

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

For any set $X$ let $[X]^2 = \big\{\{a,b\}: a\neq b\in X\big\}$. We say that a graph $G$ is *self-complementary* if $G\cong \bar{G}$ where $\bar{G} = (V, [V]^2\setminus E)$.

Given an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, is there a collection ${\cal C}$ of pairwise non-isomorphic self-complementary graphs on the vertex set $\kappa$ such that ${\cal C} = 2^\kappa$?

Comment: Do you have a family of $2^\kappa$ many pairwise no-isomorphic graphs on every cardinal $\kappa$?

Comment: Yes, see [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306117/infinite-graph-with-lots-of-non-isomorphic-induced-subgraphs).

Comment: Thank you! More precisely, one should look at this answer of @Wojowu: https://mathoverflow.net/a/281040/61536

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know, there are $2^\kappa $ nonisomorphic graphs of cardinality $\kappa$ for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$. (In fact there are $2^\kappa$ nonisomorphic *trees* of cardinality $\kappa$, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281039/mutually-non-isomorphic-connected-graphs-on-kappa-points/358126#358126).) I will show how to turn them into nonisomorphic self-complementary graphs of the same cardinality.

Given a graph $G$ of cardinality $\kappa$, let $G_1,G_2$ be two copies of $G$, and let $H_1,H_2$ be two copies of the complement of $G$, and add edges joining all vertices of $G_1$ to all vertices of $H_1$, all vertices of $H_1$ to all vertices of $H_2$, and all vertices of $H_2$ to all vertices of $G_2$. (In other words, we take the self-complementary graph $P_4$ and replace the end vertices with copies of $G$, the internal vertices with copies of $\overline G$.) In this way we get a self-complementary graph $S$ of cardinality $\kappa$.

To recover $G$ from $S$, choose a vertex $y_0$ of eccentricity $3$ and let $X$ be the set of all vertices $x$ such that $d(x,y_0)=3$; then the subgraph of $S$ induced by $X$ is a copy of $G$.